# "Simple 2D illustrations" question <- main or meta?

Tags: discussion

I posted a ["Share Your Knowledge" question and answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/405/how-to-produce-simple-2d-illustrations-to-accompany-geometry-answers) about how to use Postscript (and tools) to produce an image to accompany answers.

But should it be on the Main Site, since the subject matter is our very subject matter?

Or should it be on Meta, since the purpose is to assist in writing well-illustrated answers?

Answer (score 1):

Theres really nothing wrong with wanting to share info. Its early days so some questions are bound to be a bit synthetic.

Going forward though its not a terribly good strategy as its hard to ask a question you know the answer to. Without

1. scoping it too tight
2. scoping it too lose

So i dont know. In some way its a meta question because it asks about making drawings for posts. But then it could be phrased differently and then its fine.