# "2D Illustrations Question" - help crafting the question?

Tags: discussion

There are currently 3 close votes on my question "[How to produce simple 2D illustrations to accompany geometry answers?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/405/how-to-produce-simple-2d-illustrations-to-accompany-geometry-answers)". One for Off-Topic, One for Too Broad, And One for Too Subjective.

This suggests to me that there are multiple problems I might address, but no clear relative priorities among them.

I imagine the "off-topic" voter might be satisfied with a migration to meta, as suggested in [this related meta question](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/simple-2d-illustrations-question-main-or-meta).

"Too Subjective" could be addressed by stipulating that you must link to an actual post on the SE network where such an illustration was in fact used to assist a mathy explanation <-- an objective criterion. This would disqualify the Powerpoint answer.

"Too Broad" kinda cuts to the heart, I fear. The initial revision was clearly "too narrow". Is there a middle-ground to be struck?

Other ideas?

Comment: I think this might depend on the outcome of the [discussion on whether such questions belong on meta or main](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/147/simple-2d-illustrations-question-main-or-meta). I can imagine a single general post on meta with lots of answers for different illustration methods, whereas on main they would probably be better as separate more specific questions.

Comment: On an earlier one, I just left a comment explaining that it was contrived: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997536/how-do-you-keep-the-roll-operator-straight . Maybe something like that would help.

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close as "primarily opinion-based", even though I think it's a pretty interesting and valuable question (I even posted an answer to it), because I don't see how you could decide objectively which answer is the best.  For instance, I recommended Inkscape and someone else recommended Adobe Illustrator. Which program is "better" for making diagrams with is a matter of personal taste and experience, as well as access to the software.

It's also not really on-topic, except accidentally, to the extent that creating diagrams might call on some graphics knowledge, or involve a little programming. You could imagine many communities on SE having this same question, but it would not be remotely on-topic in most of them.

Migrating to meta might be the best thing to do with this question. I wouldn't want to get rid of it entirely, as I do think it is valuable, and meta is more OK with opinion-based questions and answers.

Comment: Oh, if *that's all*, I can simply accept my own answer. That was my original intent anyway. Postscript is clearly the best for OP. :) (to the first point.)

Comment: I didnt actually suggest illustrator i said that that is what i use, i said inkscape is certainly an option (i dont like how inkscape snaps). Also i do write postscript as a share this interest with @loserdroog but still... Also i wanted to link some additional places to go to.